# Non-unital algebras are subalgebras of endomorphism algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an algebra, not necessarily with an identity element, over a field $F$. How to show that $A$ is a subalgebra of the algebra of endomorphisms of a vector space $V$ over $F$?

Source: Exercise 6.1.3 of Herstein's Topics in Algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first embed $A$ into a unital algebra $\hat A$ (as in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29#Adjoining_an_identity_element)) and then you can use the standard embedding for unital algebras (sending $a\in A$ to $m_a\in \textrm{End}_F(A)$).